# Case assignment rule fires but doesn't send email when case is created by trigger

Tags: trigger, case

We have created a Trigger that creates a Case and the correct case assignment rule is fired. The case is correctly assigned to a queue, but the email notification is not sent.

Is there anything specific to be enabled when the case is created by trigger?

Comment: Show screen shot of your assignment rules for the queue assignment. Do you have the email check box checked?

Comment: It is checked, I ccorrected the answer though. The problem occurs when the case is created by a trigger, case created manually do not have this problem

Comment: did you look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm?search_text=emailheader